# Infinite flux of finite fluxes. Or: how to reconnect to a websocket steam without completing the flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is anywhere near best practice. If not, I'd like to know!

I'm building a system that reacts to external events posted on websockets. After authentication I can request events to be emitted and listen for them on a single flux. I can attach actuators to that flux to do stuff (think home automation, button presses turn on lights).

A problem occurs when the websocket connection drops: The flux completes and I have to re-attach all the listening actuators to a new flux on a new connection. I thought it might be easier to have an infinite flux that just starts emitting again when there is a new connection with new events (auth and requesting the events has to be done again during startup of new connection of course).

I came up with a solution that does what I want it to do, but it feels like a big hack:

```
    private Flux<String> finite() {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(10)).handle((i, sink) -> {
            if (i == 10) {
                sink.complete();
            } else {
                sink.next(i);
            }
        }).map(it -> "hi :" + it).take(100);
    }

    public static class Holder {
        @Setter
        FluxSink<Object> sink;

        public void next(EmitterProcessor<String> output) {
            sink.next(output);
        }
    }


    EmitterProcessor<String> output;
    Holder holder;

    @DisplayName("Should create infinite flux of finite fluxes")
    @Test
    public void infiniteFlux() throws InterruptedException {

        AtomicInteger count1 = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicInteger count2 = new AtomicInteger(0);
        holder = new Holder();
        ConnectableFlux flux = Flux.create(fluxSink -> holder.setSink(fluxSink)).map(it -> (Flux) it).flatMap(it -> it).publish();

        flux.connect();
        flux.subscribe((it) -> count1.incrementAndGet());
        Thread.sleep(150);
        output = EmitterProcessor.create();
        finite().subscribeWith(output);
        holder.next(output);

        Thread.sleep(150);
        flux.subscribe((it) -> count2.incrementAndGet());
        output = EmitterProcessor.create();
        finite().subscribeWith(output);
        holder.next(output);
        Thread.sleep(150);
        assertEquals(20, count1.get());
        assertEquals(10, count2.get());

    }
```

Can this maybe be done in a way with a processor in stead? Or should I forget about it and reconnect everything on completion of the websocket connection?

This is my current websocket implementation. I don't really like that I need to "know" all the types of events when starting to listen, but that is because I'm still not 100% sure how to handle sending and receiving with websockets

```
    public void startListening(Flux<HaEventRequest> eventRequests) {
        Mono<String> login = Mono.just(loginPayload());
        Flux<String> subscribe = eventRequests
                .doOnNext(req -> log.info("Registering: " + req.getEventType()))
                .map(Json::write);
        Flux<String> input = login.concatWith(subscribe);

        EmitterProcessor<HaEventResponse> output = EmitterProcessor.create();

        Mono<Void> sessionMono = client.execute(URI.create(wsUrl), session -> session.send(input.map(session::textMessage))
                                                                                     .thenMany(session.receive()
                                                                                                      .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                                                                                                      .map(message -> Json.read(message, HaEventResponse.class))
                                                                                                      .filter(eventResponse -> eventResponse.getEvent() != null)
                                                                                                      .subscribeWith(output)
                                                                                                      .then())
                                                                                     .then());

        eventFlux = output.doOnSubscribe(s -> sessionMono.subscribe())
                          .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> log.error("Error occured during web request. Dumping it: ", throwable));
    }


    public Flux<HaEventResponse> streamEvents(String eventType) {
        return eventFlux.filter(eventResponse -> eventResponse.getEvent()
                                                              .getEventType()
                                                              .equals(eventType));
    }
```

Comment: `A problem occurs when the websocket connection drops` why does it drop?

Comment: Also why are you using connectable fluxes, emitters etc. etc to test your code if you want to unit test functions you can just use the step verifier. Feels like you are overcomplicating your code waaay waaay too much.

Comment: The websocket connection drops because the other application is restarting. I'm using connectable fluxes because I need it to be hot for this "hack" to work.
I'm not actually unit testing any real code here, just trying stuff which is easier with a unit test. Also I think the stepverifier cannot really be used here because it blocks. The atomic int is there just to verify something.
I've added my current websocket code to illustrate where I started off from

Comment: also I totally agree that this code feels way over complicated for what I want to do: keep trying to reconnect to a dropped websocket connection.

Comment: After reading up on the full project reactor documenation it seems that Sinks is the future and processors are (almost) a thing of the past. This would indeed mean a similar solution using Flux.create should work fine.
In the case of the websocket client, I have uses a similar solution.